# Is it possible to implement Entity Framework's Code First in Monotouch / Xamarin?

Tags: ios, entity-framework, xamarin.ios, ef-code-first, xamarin

Does anyone know if it is possible to use the Entity Framework Code First approach when developing applications using Monotouch? I appear to be at a stumbling block with the lack of [System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/system.data/) support in the System.Data library.

If this is not possible, what other similar options are available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd look at SQLiteNet, link to the Component Store : [Sqllite Net](http://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/sqlite-net)

That will help you get started.  I am assuming, your post relates to using a local SQLLite database to store or cache data on the client mobile application.

Basically, you create your own classes, with attribute markups.  You can delete and Insert, but updates to your objects require sql statements. There is a link at the top of that getting started page, to the full documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I'm not necessarily concerned with using SQLite (although this project will). I was hoping to use the Code First approach and eliminate or minimize the amount of SQL required in the application.

Comment: Effectively, sqlitenet is the closest you will get to the "code first" approach you are looking for.. minus updates.

Comment: After much research, this appears to be the best solution to date. Also, the [SQLite-Net Extensions](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions) from TwinCoders is a great add-on.

Comment: Thanks, I might just end up using the Extension.  -grins-

Comment: Vici coolstorage is another solution but it looks that the project is dead for some time. http://viciproject.com/wiki/Projects/CoolStorage/MonoTouch